# AppEngine endpoint framework v2 sample authentication with firebase return response 401 Invalid credentials

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using the appengine [endpoints-framework-v2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/endpoints-frameworks-v2/backend) java sample. In this sample there is an endpoint called *getUserEmailFirebase* which should authenticated firebase user but it does not work

```
@ApiMethod(
  path = "firebase_user",
  httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET,
  authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
  issuerAudiences = {@ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", 
   audiences = {"my-project-id"})}
  )
public Email getUserEmailFirebase(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
if (user == null) {
  throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
}

Email response = new Email();
response.setEmail(user.getEmail());
return response;
```

}

I tried to send the request with an Authorization header inculding the firebase user id token but I'm getting 401 response, Also tried to add 'Bearer ' at the begining of the token but I get the same result. Even tried to follow this appengine guide [Authenticating Users (Frameworks)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users-frameworks) without success.

The token is retrieved by AngularFire SDK using firebaseUser.getIdToken(), I have used the Firebase server sdk to authenticated users successfuly but it doesn't work using the above method

Can you help?

Comment: Did you get the answer?